# How can I go to previous activity with the fragment the activity was showing

Tags: java, android

I have two activities, Activity A and Activity B. Now Activity A has 3 `Fragments` one of which launches activity B. When I press the action bar button it returns to activity A but shows the default `Fragment`. Am using `navUtils.navigateupFromSameTask` to go back to previous `Activity`.

How can I have the latest `Fragment` the user used show instead of the default one that shows up when user launches app the first time? For example when app launches it shows `Fragment` one. when user goes to `Fragment` 2 and launches activity B from it I want to go back to the previous activity showing fragment 2

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

in the onCreate method I have

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragment = new RadioSound();
    selectItem(0);
}
```

then `selectItem`:

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
 activeFrag = position;
 if(position == 0){
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
 }
 else if(position == 1){
     if(conv == null)
     conv = new Conversations();
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, conv).commit();
 } else{
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, (new Preferences())).commit();
 }
    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(fragments[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Comment: How do you add the fragments in your Activity A? Normally androids fragment manager will deal with restoring the last shown fragment.

Comment: @AndroidGuy Sorry for the late reply but my internet connection was down for while.Added the code for adding the fragment

Comment: @NehaShukla: hi, I've noticed that you've been adding inline code spans (`like this`) to posts when editing; these are only meant for actual code in sentences. Also, please make sure to fix as many of the issues in a post that you can find -- stuff like "thanks in advance" and "please help" isn't necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return from activity B to activity A you recreate your fragments, so it will always show your fragment1 instead of your desired fragment2.

Your problem is, that you trust on savedInstanceState to decide if your fragments should be recreated or not. However, `onSaveInstanceState()` is only called, when the activity gets destroyed, which will not instantly happen when you navigate to the next activity.

You should query the `FragmentManager` in your `onCreate()` method of activity A, if fragments are already added, otherwise you do your initial fragment creation. In order to do so, I would add an TAG to better find your fragments.

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG_CONVERSATION = "frag_conv";
...
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, conv, FRAGMENT_TAG_CONVERSATION).commit();
```

You can then check, if you already added the fragment:

```
 if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG_CONVERSATION) == null))
     // only add it here
```